# How to mark part dirty when a text field value is changed?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I have `Part` containing a `TreeViewer` with `Node`s and each `Node` has a `name` property. I have a text field to edit the name of the currently selected node. I have bound the current selection and this text field as below:

```java
IViewerObservableValue observedElementSingleSelection = ViewersObservables
            .observeSingleSelection(treeViewer);

IObservableValue detailValue = PojoProperties.value(Node.PROPERTY_NAME, String.class)
            .observeDetail(observedElementSingleSelection);
ISWTObservableValue observableNameText = WidgetProperties.text(SWT.Modify)
            .observe(nameText);
dataBindingContext.bindValue(observableNameText, detailValue);
```

Now I would like to mark the part with this `treeViewer` as dirty whenever the user edits the name of any `Node`.

When this `Part` opens the `Node`s are retrieved from the database and the tree is created. If I add a `ModifyListener` to the text field to mark the Part dirty then on initial loading the `Part` is marked dirty, which I do not want. Is there any way to mark the `Part` dirty only when the user edits the name of any `Node` but not at the time of initial loading?

I have tried to set `UpdateStrategy`so that the data binding is one-way i.e. only from view to model, but then on selection the `Node` name does not appear in the text field.

I have tried with `KeyListener`, but then I have to filter all non-printable keys to mark the `Part` as dirty. Is there any better solution?

Comment: I suggest you to first load the model and setup bindings/listeners/etc. afterwards. Then it should not get dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `ModifyListener` after the load has been done, or remove the modify listener while the load is being done, or set a flag during the load that the modify listener can test and not set the part to be dirty.

Comment: My flow in `@PostConstruct` method is like this:

1. Create TreeViewer and populate it with Nodes.
2. Create text field.
3. Setup the databinding.
4. Add the modify listener.

But the data binding actually works on selection of a node. So when the Part is opened the root node is by default selected and the name of the root node is shown in the text field. This marks the Part as dirty.

By the way is there a way to set MDirtyable to true directly with data binding?

Comment: You may be able to use an `IChangeListener` on the model observable value.